# Has a reenactment of the firing of a carcass projectile ever been filmed?

Tags: europe, weapons

From a [Scientific American blog](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/do-fireworks-resemble-the-true-sights-and-sounds-of-the-u-s-s-key-historical-battles/), on a "carcass" round:

> an explosive mortar shell ([developed by the French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carcass_(projectile)#History)) wrapped with
> incendiary material, this round was fully engulfed in flame after
> being fired, streaking through the air before exploding.

[image]

[drawing of a Carcass shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carcass_(projectile))

[image]
from the article, "[The British Fire Bombing of Quebec City in 1759](https://www.militaryheritage.com/fire_bombing_quebec_1759.htm)"

Has one ever been recreated or simulated to produce a visual presentation of what it would look like in flight?